# How to bind event on create of object in SqlAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two tables `A` and `B`.
I need to create a row in table `B` (with `ForeignKey` reference), after I create a new row in table `A`.

For example:

```
class A(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'a'

    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    ...

class B(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'b'

    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    a_id = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey('a.id'), nullable=False, index=True)
    ...
```

What is the best solution for this case in SA?

I heard about events, but can't understand how to use them the best way in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sample event :

```
def update_slug(mapper, connection, target):
    target.slug = slugify(target.name)
    if target.name_en:
        target.slug_en = slugify(target.name_en)

event.listen(Post, 'before_insert', update_slug_with_date)
event.listen(Post, 'before_update', update_slug_with_date)
```

You just define a function. You need to mark it as an event (last two lines), just in your case it will be 'after_insert' and probably 'after update' on the A model.
In the function you can do something like this :

```
b = B()
b.a = target
b.save()
```

target here is the instance on which event is being raised.

**EDIT FROM THE COMMENT TO MARK THE RIGHT ANSWER** : According to docs you can't do it in event but in SessionEvents.after_flush . You should check out the docs : http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.MapperEvents.after_insert

Comment: Pawel, Thx for the help! Could you tell me why even if I do commit inside the event listener I get the TransactionClosed error? Can I use transaction inside and rollback on exception?
I can't find in documentation what types of actions can I use inside event listener (for example, session commit, sql expressions, orm actions, new transactions and etc.)

Comment: Sorry. My pointer was somewhat wrong (short term memory ;) ) : According to docs you can't do it in event but in SessionEvents.after_flush . You should check out the docs in http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.MapperEvents.after_insert