# How can I listen for the creation of a specific model and create a new one (on a different table) based on this?

Tags: postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a `User` model with a `referral_key` attribute. I'd like to create a `ReferralKeyRecord` upon creation of a user. I've read tons of documentation and StackExchange to no avail.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13693872/can-sqlalchemy-events-be-used-to-update-a-denormalized-data-cache/13765857#13765857) answer uses `after_insert()`, but I am not trying to alter or validate the class which is being inserted; I am trying to add a new object from a completely different model—and `session.add()` isn't supported.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20141382/how-to-bind-event-on-create-of-object-in-sqlalchemy) answer is closer to what I want, but the accepted answer (ultimately) uses `after_flush()`, which is far too general. I don't want to listen to events thrown whenever the DB is updated somehow. I want it to fire off when a *specific* model is created.

And something like the following...

```
@event.listens_for(User, 'after_flush')
def create_referral_record(mapper, connection, target):
    session.add(ReferralRecord(key=instances.referral_key))
    session.commit()
```

... results in `No such event 'after_flush' for target '<class 'models.User'>`. I've looked through SQLAlchemy's documentation (the core events and the ORM events) and see no events that indicate a specific model has been created. The closest thing in Mapper events is the `after_insert` method, and the closest thing in Session events is the `after_flush()` method. I imagine this is a pretty common thing to need to do, and would thus be surprised if there wasn't an easy event to listen to. I assume it'd be something like:

```
@event.listens_for(User, 'on_creation')
def create_referral_record(session, instance):
    record = ReferralRecord(key=instance.referral_key)
    session.add(record)
    session.commit()
```

Does anyone know better than I?

Comment: did you try `before_insert`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or why not create the `Referral` inside the `User` constructor?

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, relationship, Mapper
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, ForeignKey, create_engine, event


Base = declarative_base()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    def __init__(self):
        self.referral = Referral()

    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)    
    referral = relationship('Referral', uselist=False)


class Referral(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'referral'
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer(), ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
session = Session(bind=engine)

session.add(User())
session.commit()

print(session.query(User).all())
print(session.query(Referral).all())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `after_flush` [session event](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/events.html#session-events), and inside the event handler you can access the session's new objects (using `session.new`).

Example:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, relationship, Mapper
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, ForeignKey, create_engine, event


Base = declarative_base()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)


class Referral(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'referral'
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer(), ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
session = Session(bind=engine)


@event.listens_for(session, 'after_flush')
def session_after_flush(session, flush_context):
    for obj in session.new:
        if isinstance(obj, User):
            session.add(Referral(user_id=obj.id))


session.add(User())
session.commit()

print(session.query(User).all())
print(session.query(Referral).all())
```

Running this outputs:

```
[<__main__.User object at 0x00000203ABDF5400>]
[<__main__.Referral object at 0x00000203ABDF5710>]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I mentioned in the post that I don't want to use `after_flush` because that's an event that isn't specific to the `User` model. It's triggered after *every* flush.

Comment: ... yes I saw that part of the question a bit late