# Two-way foreign keys on different attributes, one-to-one and one-to-many

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have two models: `User` and `ReferralKey`, with these requirements:

- On creation of `User`, a `ReferralKey` is automatically created and added to the DB
- `ReferralKey` keeps track of which users were referred by it
- `ReferralKey` keeps track of which user owns it

As per the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59383591/how-can-i-listen-for-the-creation-of-a-specific-model-and-create-a-new-one-on-a/59392696#59392696) question, the best solution seems to be to create the `ReferralKey` within the constructor of `User`. The solution to the other two require foreign keys, and seems really messy—entangling the tables together in such a way that I might as well put them in the same table.

The solution to the first looks like this:

```
def User(model):
    id = Column(BigInteger(), autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    referral_key = relationship('ReferralKey', uselist=False)
    ...
    def __init__(self):
        self.referral_key = ReferralKey()

def ReferralKey(model):
    id = Column(BigInteger(), autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(BigInteger(), ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='SET NULL'), nullable=True)
```

This works as intended, and solves the first and third points. The problem arises when trying to solve the 2nd. This (for some reason) necessitates a new foreign key in `User`, which necessitates the declaration of a `relationship` in both `User` and `ReferralKey` to (I guess) disambiguate the foreign keys:

```
def User(model):
    id = Column(BigInteger(), autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    referral_key = relationship('ReferralKey', uselist=False)
    referrer_id = Column(BigInteger(), ForeignKey('referral_key.id', ondelete='SET NULL'))
    referrer = relationship('ReferralKey', foreign_keys=['referrer_id'], backref='used_by')
    ...
    def __init__(self):
        self.referral_key = ReferralKey()

def ReferralKey(model):
    __tablename__='referral_key'
    id = Column(BigInteger(), autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(BigInteger(), ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='SET NULL'), nullable=True)
    user = relationship('User', foreign_keys=['user_id'])
```

I've tried all different permutations of `relationship` and `ForeignKey`, and always get the same error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.CircularDependencyError: Can't sort tables for DROP; an unresolvable foreign key dependency exists between tables: referral_key, users.  Please ensure that the ForeignKey and ForeignKeyConstraint objects involved in the cycle have names so that they can be dropped using DROP CONSTRAINT.
```

Ultimately, my problem is that I just don't understand what I'm doing. Why do I need to change the `User` table *at all* in order to keep track of things on the `ReferralKey` table? What purpose does the `relationship` declaration serve—why is it ambiguous without this declaration? If `User` has a foreign key referencing `ReferralKey` and `ReferralKey` has a foreign key referencing `User`—and either of these should be set to `NULL` in case of deletion, why does SQL need more information than that?

Why can't I just have:

```
def User(model):
    id = Column(BigInteger(), autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    def __init__(self):
        ReferralKey(user_id=self.id)

def ReferralKey(model):
    __tablename__='referral_key'
    id = Column(BigInteger(), autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(BigInteger(), ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='SET NULL'), nullable=True)
    used_by = [list of user IDs]

    def __init__(self, user_id):
        if user_id:
            self.user_id == user_id
```

This feels to me so much cleaner and more intuitive. If I want to add (or remove!) referral keys, I hardly have to worry about adding things to `User` because it's mostly independent of the functioning of the referral keys. Why do I need to add a column in the `user` table to keep track of something that I want the `ReferralKey` to keep track of?

I'm totally ignorant of this, basically. Would anyone mind helping me out?

Comment: Can you please give details for the relationship: A user can have zero or one referral key? A referral key is always linked to exactly one user? which direction is one-to-many, which one-to-may?

Comment: @AndiSchroff When a user is created, they have exactly one referral key associated w/ their account—they own that key so that other users can use it (one-to-one; ForeignKey on ReferralKey). Also, a referral key should keep track of which users used it when they were registering (one-to-many; ForeignKey on User). Part of my question also regards my ignorance as to why this can't all be done via the ReferralKey model (why do we have to entangle the two so much?)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

It relies on the information:

- A user creates his own master key on registration.
- A user may register a slave key when he registers, but maybe not.

This way the foreign keys remain in one table but you need to differentiate between them..

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base= declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    own_referral_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('referral_key.id'))
    own_referral_key = relationship('ReferralKey', foreign_keys=[own_referral_id], back_populates='owner')
    signup_referral_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('referral_key.id'))
    signup_referral_key = relationship('ReferralKey', foreign_keys=[signup_referral_id], back_populates='signups')
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.own_referral_key = ReferralKey()
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class ReferralKey(Base):
    __tablename__ = "referral_key"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    owner = relationship('User', foreign_keys=[User.own_referral_id], back_populates='own_referral_key', uselist=False)
    signups = relationship('User', foreign_keys=[User.signup_referral_id], back_populates='signup_referral_key', uselist=True)


e = create_engine("sqlite://")
Base.metadata.create_all(e)

s = Session(e)

u1 = User()
s.add(u1)
s.commit()

u2 = User(signup_referral_id = u1.own_referral_id)
u3 = User(signup_referral_id = u1.own_referral_id)

s.add(u2)
s.add(u3)
s.commit()

print(u1.own_referral_key.signups)
```